# Hide an app on an AVD

Tags: android-emulator

I want to perform exploratory testing on an app my team is developing, and for this, I'd like to be able to manually hide and unhide apps on an AVD. Is there a way I can do this?

I observe that with adb shell, `pm hide $PACKAGE` is available, but I don't appear to have permission. The terminal shows me the output:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 2000 nor current process has android.permission.MANAGE_USERS.

Is there a workaround on an AVD? I'm on Android 11. Can I start adb shell with the necessary permissions?

(I really don't want to have to write an app, make it the device manager, and run it to hide other apps.)

Comment: What does `pm disable-user $PACKAGE` does?

Comment: That gives the output `Package cs.rcherz new state: disabled-user`. After having done so, though, `pm hide cs.rcherz` still gives the error message about `android.permission.MANAGE_USERS` which is printed above.

Comment: One you have already disabled an app, why do you want to continue with `hide`?

Comment: @Firelord I want apps hidden because I'm doing exploratory testing for our MDM app. In particular, I want to verify its behaviours with respect to hidden apps. Being able to hide the apps with a simple execution from the shell would facilitate this exploration.